# Cant access json file from 000webhost.com

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

I am using `000webhost.com` to host my files, and i can access them via web browser, is there any setting that I should be aware on the webhost to make my files available to my android app.

I cant access json file or even images folder via android, when retrofit's `onFailure()` method gets executed, the `printStackTrace` method says:

```
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http": No address associated with hostname
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:457)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
04-05 16:41:49.342 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
04-05 16:41:49.343 23509-23509/com.hanselandpetal.catalog W/System.err:     ... 20 more
```

Here the http address I am using:

```
public static final String ENDPOINT =
            "http://services.hanselandpetal.com";
    public static final String ENDPOINT2 =
            "http://ajay_pyaraka.site88.net";

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT2)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        FlowersAPI service = retrofit.create(FlowersAPI.class);
        Call<List<Flower>> call = service.getFeed2();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Flower>> call, Response<List<Flower>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    flowerList = response.body();
                    updateDisplay();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Flower>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
```

I was able to get from the first var ENDPOINT, but not with the second ENDPOINT2

Comment: Your host name is incorrect. try with correct name or ip address.

Comment: `No address associated with hostname` it clearly shows there is something wrong with your url.

Comment: Show some code please ... Anyways, `Unable to resolve host "http"`... You only are trying to connect to the string "http", not any Web address

Comment: updated my question, check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the under score present in the domain is the problem. I tried with another domain name with no underscores and it worked